# How to have a view that displays the front camera view or a black screen if its an iphone 2g/3g/3gs? I need a view that it's like a mirror?

Tags: iphone

There is a way to do that?
Thank you very much for your time
I need only the view from the front camera or a black screen if its an iphone 2g/3g/3gs...

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]
```

Should return true if there is a front camera, false if not.  I've never had the opportunity to test this function on a phone with a front camera though.